# Duda relación m:m método sync Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Tengo una duda con el método `sync` de Laravel 5.4
estas son mis tablas(solo los campos importantes), es una relación muchos a muchos.

Estas son mis tablas:

```
cometido = id,fecha
persona  = id, nombre
cometido_persona = id, id_cometido, id_persona,estado
```

Esta es la relación de "cometidos"

```
public function personas(){
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Persona','cometido_persona',
'id_cometido','id_persona','estado');
```

Esta es la relación de "personas"

```
    public function cometidos(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Cometido','cometido_persona')
     ->withPivot('id_persona','id_cometido','estado');
         }
```

No se muy bien si esta bien hecha la relación, vi la documentación pero me sigue generando dudas.
El método `sync` me actuliza bien en la tabla pivote:

```
 $cometido->personas()->sync($request->"select que entrega array",['estado' => 1]);
```

Pero lo que no me esta guardando es el estado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando usas sync debes pasar el valor de los campos adicionales que deseas modificar en cada Id, para lo cual puedes hacer esto, asumiendo que sea el mismo valor para TODOS los Id:

```
$elementos  = (array) $request->elementos;

$datosAdicionales = array_fill(0, count($elementos), ['estado' => 1]);

$valores  = array_combine($elementos,$datosAdicionales);

$cometido->personas()->sync($valores);
```